# JAXB not unmarshalling all fields

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

I am working on a JavaFX application which facilitates all kind of sport related training sessions. Each session consists of multiple exercises, whereas each exercise is repeated multiple times in a few sets. I created some test data and marshalled it. As it turned out, some fields of the Exercise class objects were written but not all of them. By adding the @XmlElement(name="someTagName") tag to each getter of each field I managed that all fields are marshalled and the xml file looks like expected. However, when I unmarshall the xml file, only those fields, which were written without the @XmlElement tag are read and most of the fields only have the default value from the constructor. What am I missing in order to unmarshall all fields?

Here is the class that I want to marshall/unmarshall
package domain;

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Exercise extends SelectableDomainObj {

    protected StringProperty name;
    protected StringProperty mediaFilePath;
    protected IntegerProperty repsPerSet;
    protected IntegerProperty numOfSets;
    protected IntegerProperty breakBetweenSetsInSecs;
    protected IntegerProperty displayTimeInSecs;
    protected DoubleProperty startSpeed;
    protected DoubleProperty endSpeed;
    protected BooleanProperty withMetronom;
    protected BooleanProperty showIntro;

    /**
     * Set some reasonable default values from lifting domain
     */
    public Exercise() {
        mediaFilePath = new SimpleStringProperty();
        name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        
        numOfSets = new SimpleIntegerProperty(3);
        repsPerSet = new SimpleIntegerProperty(8);
        breakBetweenSetsInSecs = new SimpleIntegerProperty(60);
        displayTimeInSecs = new SimpleIntegerProperty(-1);
        startSpeed = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);
        endSpeed = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);
        withMetronom = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        showIntro = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    }
    
    @XmlElement(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }
    
    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="mediaFilePath")
    public String getMediaFilePath() {
        return mediaFilePath.get();
    }

    public void setMediaFilePath(String mediaFilePath) {
        this.mediaFilePath.set(mediaFilePath);
    }
    
    public StringProperty mediaFilePathProperty() {
        return mediaFilePath;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="repsPerSet")
    public Integer getRepsPerSet() {
        return repsPerSet.get();
    }

    public void setRepsPerSet(int repsPerSet) {
        this.repsPerSet.set(repsPerSet);
    }
    
    public IntegerProperty repsPerSetProperty() {
        return repsPerSet;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="numOfSets")
    public int getNumOfSets() {
        return numOfSets.get();
    }

    public void setNumOfSets(int numOfSets) {
        this.numOfSets.set(numOfSets);
    }
    
    public IntegerProperty numOfSetsProperty() {
        return numOfSets;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="breakBetweenSetsInSec")
    public Integer getBreakBetweenSetsInSecs() {
        return breakBetweenSetsInSecs.get();
    }

    public void setBreakBetweenSetsInSecs(int breakBetweenSetsInSecs) {
        this.breakBetweenSetsInSecs.set(breakBetweenSetsInSecs);
    }
    
    public IntegerProperty displayTimeInSecsProperty() {
        return displayTimeInSecs;
    }
    
    @XmlElement(name="displayTimeInSecs")
    public Integer getDisplayTimeInSecs() {
        return displayTimeInSecs.get();
    }

    public void setDisplayTimeInSecs(int displayTime) {
        this.displayTimeInSecs.set(displayTime);
    }
    
    public IntegerProperty breakBetweenSetsInSecsProperty() {
        return breakBetweenSetsInSecs;
    }
    
    @XmlElement(name="showIntro")
    public Boolean isShowIntro() {
        return showIntro.getValue();
    }

    public void setShowIntro(boolean showIntro) {
        this.showIntro.set(showIntro);
    }
    
    public BooleanProperty showIntroProperty() {
        return showIntro;
    }
    
    @XmlElement(name="withMetronom")
    public Boolean isWithMetronom() {
        return withMetronom.getValue();
    }

    public void setWithMetronom(boolean withMetronom) {
        this.withMetronom.set(withMetronom);
    }
    
    public BooleanProperty withMetronomProperty() {
        return withMetronom;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="startSpeed")
    public Double getStartSpeed() {
        return startSpeed.get();
    }

    public void setStartSpeed(double startDuration) {
        this.startSpeed.set(startDuration);
    }
    
    public DoubleProperty startSpeedProperty() {
        return startSpeed;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="endSpeed")
    public Double getEndSpeed() {
        return endSpeed.get();
    }

    public void setEndSpeed(double endDuration) {
        this.endSpeed.set(endDuration);
    }
    
    public DoubleProperty endSpeedProperty() {
        return endSpeed;
    }

    public double getSpeed(int rep) {
        
        if(getStartSpeed().equals(getEndSpeed())) {
            return getStartSpeed();
        }

        double min, max;

        if(getStartSpeed() > getEndSpeed()) {
            max = getStartSpeed(); 
            min = getEndSpeed();
        } else {
            min = getStartSpeed(); 
            max = getEndSpeed();
        }

        double diff = max - min;
        double increment = diff / (getRepsPerSet()-1);
        
        return min + rep * increment;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

I used this to marshall

```
public void save(Session session) {
        try {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Session.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.marshal(session, new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".sifuSays/sessions/" + session.getName() + ".xml"));
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot save session " + session.getName());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

which generates the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Session>
    <exerciseList>
        <exercise>
            <selected>true</selected>
            <breakBetweenSetsInSec>5</breakBetweenSetsInSec>
            <displayTimeInSecs>-1</displayTimeInSecs>
            <endSpeed>3.0</endSpeed>
            <mediaFilePath>Tan Pak Gan.mp4</mediaFilePath>
            <name>Solo Tan Pak Gan Drill</name>
            <numOfSets>2</numOfSets>
            <repsPerSet>3</repsPerSet>
            <showIntro>false</showIntro>
            <startSpeed>1.0</startSpeed>
            <withMetronom>false</withMetronom>
        </exercise>
        <exercise>
            <selected>true</selected>
            <breakBetweenSetsInSec>5</breakBetweenSetsInSec>
            <displayTimeInSecs>-1</displayTimeInSecs>
            <endSpeed>1.0</endSpeed>
            <mediaFilePath>Chain Punches.mp4</mediaFilePath>
            <name>Solo Ein-Arm-Zyklus</name>
            <numOfSets>2</numOfSets>
            <repsPerSet>4</repsPerSet>
            <showIntro>true</showIntro>
            <startSpeed>1.0</startSpeed>
            <withMetronom>true</withMetronom>
        </exercise>
        <exercise>
            <selected>true</selected>
            <breakBetweenSetsInSec>5</breakBetweenSetsInSec>
            <displayTimeInSecs>10</displayTimeInSecs>
            <endSpeed>1.0</endSpeed>
            <mediaFilePath>birddogs.jpg</mediaFilePath>
            <name>Stetching</name>
            <numOfSets>1</numOfSets>
            <repsPerSet>1</repsPerSet>
            <showIntro>true</showIntro>
            <startSpeed>1.0</startSpeed>
            <withMetronom>false</withMetronom>
        </exercise>
    </exerciseList>
    <breakBetweenExercisesInSec>10</breakBetweenExercisesInSec>
    <name>MMA - Solo</name>
</Session>
```

and this is the unmarshaller code

```
public ObservableList<Session> loadSessions() {
        
        sessions = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        
        try {
            List<File> xmlSessionFiles = Stream.of(
                    new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".sifuSays/sessions/").listFiles())
                    .filter(file -> !file.isDirectory())
                    .filter(file -> file.getName().endsWith("xml"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            for(File xmlSessionFile: xmlSessionFiles) {
                JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Session.class);
                Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
                Session session = (Session) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlSessionFile);
                sessions.add(session);
            }

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot load sessions");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return sessions;
    }
```

While numOfSets is marshalled, repsPerset is not. Neither startSpeed or stopSpeed are unmarshalled and neither withMetronom or showIntro. But name and mediaFilePath are marshalled. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up boxed (`Double`, `Integer`) and unboxed (`double`, `int`) types. I recommend sticking to boxed types for marshalling since otherwise you'll end up with things set to `0` that you weren't expecting.